nuget restore with a switch to choose package version
I got a project file with a property1 like this
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" TreatAsLocalProperty="Property1">
 <PropertyGroup>
    ....
 <Property1></Property1>
</PropertyGroup>
 <Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(Property1)'==''">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <Property1>DefaultValue</Property1>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
  </Choose>
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Property1)' == 'DefaultValue'">
 <PackageReference Include="nuget.package.xy" Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Property1)' == 'OtherValue'">
 <PackageReference Include="nuget.package.xy" Version="1.10.0" />
</ItemGroup>

Is there a possibility to pass Property1 value to
nuget restore project.csproj -configFile Nuget.Config

to decide which package version to restore? Or could it be done in Nuget.Config somehow?
